# Socket IO handshake working with Postman but not in code

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm trying to get the data from this **https://pollution.gov.np/gss/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1617892805849.** I'm doing a get to get the sid, then a post with 32:42["client_request","Pollution"] in the body and then another get to retrieve the data. It works perfectly on postman but when I'm trying to do it in JS with request-promise-native I got a **"301 Page moved permanently"** on the post and I can't understand why. I checked the url I pass to my request is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have here is with `request-promise-native`. It doesn't follow redirects but Postman does.
If you are using `node.js` for that I'd suggest you to use `axios` or `node-fetch`.
By the way `request` and `request-promise-native` are deprecated so it's better not to use them at all.

Comment: Can you please explain more in details what do you mean by redirects? What is redirect in this case?

Comment: @Gajiu here is an article that will help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections